# How can I take an Array of objects from one method to another and return a new object?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need to use the **array** from my **main method** and **transfer** it over to my **getBook method** and **then return a newly created object** back to the array in the main method.

I decided to transfer the array over to the next method by doing it the same way I did with the scanner which works until I need to call the method when it errors.

```
public class BookShopApplication 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner (System.in);
        Book [] books = new Book [10];

        for (int i = 0; i > books.length; i++) 
        {
            books[i] = getBook(kybd, Book books[])
        }

    }

    public static Book[] getBook(Scanner kybd, Book books[]) 
    {


        System.out.println("What is the title of the next book?");
        String readTitle = kybd.nextLine();

        System.out.println("What is thr title of thje next book?");
        String readAuthor = kybd.nextLine();

        if (readAuthor == null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
            {
                books[i] = new Book();
                books[i].Book(readTitle);
            }

        }
        else 
        {
             for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
            {
                books[i] = new Book();

                books[i].Book(readAuthor, readTitle);


            }

        }
    return books;
    }
}
```

The results I need is for the books to be returned to the array and stored.

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: @Jaquarh line 14 not a statement

Comment: `public static Book[] getBook(Scanner kybd, Book[] books)` - books is the variable, `Book[]` is the datatype. You're also missing a `;` after the call to the method - you have syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you do have some syntax errors:

First, in your for loop, `books[i] = getBook(kybd, Book books[])` should be replaced by `books[i] = getBook(kybd, books)` (to pass a variable as parameter to a method, just use its name!)

Second, in your method signature, replace `public static Book[] getBook(Scanner kybd, Book books[])` by `public static Book[] getBook(Scanner kybd, Book[] books)`
(Notice, it's `Book[] books`, not `Book books[]`).

Hope this helps!

Also, as Jaquarh commented, you are missing a semicolon!

**Edit:** In addition, your method `getBooks` should return one book, not an array, as pointed out by Jaquarh. Otherwise, the line
`books[i] = getBook(kybd, Book books[])` will crash.

Comment: Thank you for answering :), I have edited the code, but now I am getting an error "incompatible types Book[] cannot be converted to Book

Comment: @ShaneJones at what line are you getting this?

Comment: From getBook you are returning a Book[] and at line 11 you are specting a Book because at 7 you are declaring> Book [] books = new Book [10];

Comment: line 14,  books[i] = getBook(kybd, books);

Comment: @ShaneJones oh, okay, your method `getBooks` returns an array of books, not just one book!

Comment: What do you want this method to achieve exactly? Return one book or an array?

Comment: exactly, check the answer from @Jaquarh

Comment: Answer edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `Book` class looks some-what similar to this:

```
class Book
{
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author)
    {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

It makes more sense that you're trying to individually instance the books and store them in an array of `Book` objects.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kybd = new Scanner (System.in);
    Book [] books = new Book [10];

    // < is needed not >
    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) 
    {
        // book[] is empty, it has an index of 10 with no nodes
        // You need to create the instance to pass into the method
        books[i] = getBook(kybd, new Book());
    }
}

// This should only take the book it is working with
public static Book getBook(Scanner kybd, Book book)
{
    System.out.println("What is the title of the next book?");
    String readTitle = kybd.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is the title of the next book?");
    String readAuthor = kybd.nextLine();

    if (!readAuthor.isEmpty())
    {
        book.setTitle(readTitle);
    }

    if(!readTitle.isEmpty())
    {
        book.setAuthor(readAuthor);
    }

    return book;
}
```

You have a lot of syntax errors, also - make use of the `.isEmpty()` methods rather than using `=== null`.

**Update**: You never actually create an instance of `Book` in your loop. Also, `for (int i = 0; i > books.length; i++)` - it should be `<` not `>`.

This code should now work.

Comment: Thanks :) all working now

Comment: No worries, hope it helped

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i > books.length; i++) 
    {
        books[i] = getBook(kybd,books);
    }
```

Should do the trick and not cause an error

Also this is not valid:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
        {
            books[i] = new Book();
            **books[i].Book(readTitle);**
        }

    }
    else 
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
        {
            books[i] = new Book();

            **books[i].Book(readAuthor, readTitle);**
```

**EDITED**

Comment: It still errors with: .class expected, ; expected, cannot find symbol, unexpected type

Comment: Because `getBook` is a method, you need to end the statement with a `;`

Comment: This won't compile, as `book[]` is not valid as reference.

Comment: Even with the ; it still errors with incompatible types Book[] cannot be converted to Book